# How do i simplify 2 foreach using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

How can I do this in a more readable way?

```
 foreach (var actual in actualPositions)
 {
     foreach (var projection in projections)
     {
         var position        = Create(book, actual, projection);
         position.TargetNett = projection.DailyProjectedNet.ToString();
         yield return position;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Define "better". Readability? Performance? Something else?

Comment: Are `actionPositions` and `projections` related in any way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to simplify that? Why? It's simple and readable and understandable. You can come up with all sorts of gobbledygook that is *harder* to read but sure looks cooler. Do not! Resist the urge to be fancy.

Comment: This. Also don't spend crazy amounts of time "optimizing" stuff that takes no time. You've probably spent more time looking at it trying to make it one LINQ statement for what? What gain?

Comment: This is what I would recommend. It's easier to understand WHAT you're doing here, which isn't necessarily the case with my answer below (at least for the first version). Sometimes, more code is just better for readability and future maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

```
return 
  from actual in actualProjections
  from projection in projections
  select Create(book, actual, projection)
          .With_TargetNett(projection.DailyProjectedNet.ToString());
```

where With_TargetNett is extension

```
static Position With_TargetNett(this Position position, string targetNett)
{
 position.TargetNett = targetNett;
 return position;
}
```

Comment: Even though this is what he wants, please notice how what he originally wrote takes 5 lines, and this takes 5 + 3. Anyway, +1 for taking the time of thinking it through.

Answer (score 2):

One option you can do is to implement your own cross join, and enumerate over that. However, it's still not very pretty:

```
actualPositions.SelectMany(actual => projections.Select(project => new { actual, project }))
```

However, if you're using the .NET 4.0 or higher, you can implement a cross join extension method using Tuples (default) or your own custom selector:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> CrossJoin<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> source, IEnumerable<T2> toJoin)
{
    return source.CrossJoin(toJoin, Tuple.Create<T1, T2>);
}

public static IEnumerable<T3> CrossJoin<T1, T2, T3>(this IEnumerable<T1> source, IEnumerable<T2> toJoin, Func<T1, T2, T3> selector)
{
    return source.SelectMany(tFirst => toJoin.Select(tSecond => selector(tFirst, tSecond)));
}
```

And then this can be used a lot easier:

```
foreach(var pair in actualPositions.CrossJoin(projections))
{
    var position = Create(book, pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
    position.TargetNett = pair.Item2.DailyProjectedNet.ToString();
    yield return position;
}
// OR
return actionPositions.CrossJoin(projections, (actual, project) => { /*Code in foreach loop above here, without the "yield". */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun

```
return 
 (
  from actual in actualProjections  
  from projection in projections  
  select new {actual, projection}
 ).Select(pair => 
   {
     var position = Create(book, pair.actual, pair.projection);   
     position.TargetNett = pair.projection.DailyProjectedNet.ToString();           
     return position;
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case Linq provides less readability.
You can move the second foreach statement in a seperate method and then use Linq

```
return from actual in actualPositions
       select GetBookPositionList(actual);
```

new method:

```
private List<BookPosition> GetBookPositionList(ActualPosition actual)
{
  foreach (var projection in projections)
  {
    var position = Create(book, actual, projection);
    position.TargetNett = projection.DailyProjectedNet.ToString();
    yield return position;
  }
}
```